# How to constrain Attached Properties to only the children of one container class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

Given this code below, how one would enrich the class so as to constrain this attached property to only the children of one precise container ( lets call it "class MyContainer") ), just the way things are going with Canvas X and Y and also Grid Column and Row attached properties.

```
public class MyAttachedPropertyClass
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyAttachedProperty;
    static MyAttachedPropertyClass()
    {
        MyAttachedProperty= DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyAttached",
                                                            typeof(MyProperty),
                                                            typeof(MyAttachedPropertyClass),
                                                            new PropertyMetadata(null);
    }

    public static MyProperty GetTitleText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (MyProperty)obj.GetValue(MyAttachedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTitleText(DependencyObject obj, MyProperty value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyAttachedProperty, value);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached Properties BY DEFINITION can be attached to any class that implements DependencyObject.

You can change the implementation of the getters and setters like so:

```
public static MyProperty GetTitleText(MyContainer obj)
{
    return (MyProperty)obj.GetValue(MyAttachedProperty);
}

public static void SetTitleText(MyContainer obj, MyProperty value)
{
    obj.SetValue(MyAttachedProperty, value);
}
```

so they will only target MyContainer, but that won't really help as the real work is done in the underlying obj.SetValue / obj.GetValue, which WPF will call directly many times.

The best solution is to use to define a `Behavior<MyContainer>` and that can be attached ONLY to MyContainer. Behaviors are just sophisticated & more elegant Attached Properties, so eveything else would stay pretty much the same.

Comment: It's amazingly simple, and IMO it's the best feature of WPF4. it gives u a huge boost to productivity